# PHP/MySQL outing a table from the data base but excluding a field from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I have a form which allows the user to set what the sort the data by in the table and if it increase or decreasing order

http://damiensplace.co.uk/test/requestTableDisplay.htm

However I want the user to choose to exclude a field (Age Grade) form set the variable but been racking my brain on how to do this but only way I come up with is not neat as I basically need to write two lots of code am I missing a trick?

```
<html><head><title>MySQL Table Viewer</title></head><body>
<?php
$db_host = '****';
$db_user = '***';
$db_pwd = '***';

$sortOn = $_POST['SortOn'];
$sortIn = $_POST['SortIn'];

$database = '****';
$table = '***';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} order by {$sortOn} {$sortIn}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```

If someone can point me in the right direction I would be most grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple. Instead of running this query:

`SELECT * FROM {$table} order by {$sortOn} {$sortIn}`

run this one:

`"SELECT hats, cats, margarine FROM {$table} order by {$sortOn} {$sortIn}`

...where `hats`, `cats` and `margarine` are to be replaced by fields in your table. You can specify any number of fields in this way, even down to grabbing only a single field.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your query as follows:

```
SELECT (columns) FROM (table)
```

Do not SELECT all, it appears you only want specific columns.